# How could I use a module to pass in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so my code is like this..

```
import { brand, pageAttributes } from './config';

let render = () => {
    import('../../../../assets/css/themes/dark.scss').then(x => {
        require('../../AppRenderer');
    });
};

render();
```

basically AppRenderer is a react js file that uses brand, pageAttributes. the trick is I cannot just import my dependencies in AppRenderer since I am dynamically loading the appRenderer file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not import the styles inside `AppRenderer`:

```
import "assets/css/themes/dark.scss"
```

and then use `Suspense`:

```
<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
  <AppRenderer />
</Suspense>
```

Unless you are server-side rendering...

Comment: the theme css should be changeable on runtime but thanks this really make sense.